# ActiveDirectory Domain Description?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to get some details about the current systems Domain.
I've been able to find the Name, DomainMode and ForstMode by using the following code:

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + domain.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Domain Mode: " + domain.DomainMode);
Console.WriteLine("Forest Mode: " + domain.Forest.ForestMode);
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the domains description. Screenshot of what I am looking for:

[image: Looking for]

Any suggestions on how I can go about getting this? I don't see any attributes on the `Domain` object that seems to represent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Along with the description I was also able to get the SID using the following code:

```
            using (System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + domain.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain Mode: " + domain.DomainMode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Forest Mode: " + domain.Forest.ForestMode);

                    var sidInBytes = directoryEntry.Properties["objectSID"].Value as byte[];
                    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain SID: " + sid.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + directoryEntry.Properties["description"].Value as string);
                }
            }
```